# File path validation

Tags: c#, .net, string, validation

I have to validate user input for file path. So far what I have tried is **given below** in the code. The code works fine for some cases e.g.

C:\ (valid) (my code returns valid)

C:\(valid) (my code returns valid)

C:+space+\ (my code returns valid but I want to take it as invalid)

C:+space+ filename (my code returns valid but I want to take it as invalid)

It should consider "spaces" between and after the "\" as invalid.

```
public bool FilePathValid(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                Path.GetFullPath(path);
                Path.GetFileName(path);
                return Path.IsPathRooted(path);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                   
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**NOTE:** I only want to try regex when I have no other options because as once said you try to solve your problem with regex and ends up having two.

Comment: How do you define "validate"? You want to check if the file name actuallky exists or do you want to check for invalid chars?

Comment: @CodeCaster In short, the error that I have shown in the picture attached to the question, I want the same. I am using windows 10 and I open a file explorer, I type a path name if it is valid the file explorer opens the directory or folder and if it is invalid as shown in the picture attached it gives an error. I want to have the exact same validation. Please let me know if u require more info

Comment: @CodeCaster No. 
Only the validity of the input path by the user if the path or folder does not exist then I create a folder.

Comment: @Sefe No. Only the validity of the input path by the user if the path or folder does not exist then I create a folder but before creating a folder I just need to see whether the typed path by the user is correct in reference to windows 10 file paths.

Comment: @CodeCaster wrong !. On Windows 10 you cannot create a folder with space before or after any character, Windows trim the name so the folder always start and end with a none space character. And yes that's on NTFS.

Comment: @Franck Try doing from cmd prompt `md "    Test     "` and see if it works... It works :-)

Comment: @xanatos, Oh yes, my bad, partially right tough. It doesn't allow space at the end. "  Test  " become "  Test". On one of my windows server it doesn't create the folder with the command line at all while i can use the explorer but it does remove the space like windows 10.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have posted an image in my question which is the exact error that I want to detect, when the user types "C:\+space+ \", I want to detect it as invalid path

Comment: What are you trying to do with the path? Why not try `Directory.GetFiles(path)` or whatever it is you want to do and catch errors from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're not interested in actually validating a path nor checking whether a path points to an existing file or directory, you just want to check if a path separator is preceded or followed by a space?

Then do that:

```
if (path.Contains(@" \") || path.Contains(@"\ "))
{
    // do your magic
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I am very new to all this, so, it was difficult to explain myself but thanks alot.

Comment: No problem, just consider that others can't always understand what you're trying to do. I think I summarized it correctly in the first sentence of this answer.